# How to use a variable's string value to change a specific object's text

Tags: swift, xcode, variables

So lets say I have 3 things declared. A string variable called 'x' and 2 labels, one named 'title' and the other named 'body' . What I want to happen is this:

thevalueof 'x'.text = "whatever text I want"

I would have the value of x change throughout the code between 'title' and 'body' so that I could hopefully switch the text of either 'title' or 'body' based on the value of x

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in swift? This sounds like a JavaScript nuance that you're trying to shoehorn into a more graceful language.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Well If I'm trying to make an app in xcode, wouldn't I have to try to make it work in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could use [Property Observers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html), like `willSet`:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

let a = UILabel()
let b = UILabel()

var x: String = "Begining" {
    willSet {
        switch newValue {
        case "title":
            a.text = "A"
            b.text = "B"
            break
        case "body":
            a.text = "AA"
            b.text = "BB"
            break
        default:
            a.text = "Hello"
            b.text = "world"
        }
    }
}

x = "title"
print(a.text!)          //"A"
print(b.text!)          //"B"

x = "body"
print(a.text!)          //"AA"
print(b.text!)          //"BB" 

x = "some other string"
print(a.text!)          //"Hello"
print(b.text!)          //"world"
```

*(Here I am force-unwrapping the `text` property of the labels just for simplicity.)*

Comment: I think that this is what I needed